# Is it possible to appeal a notice of intent to assess after the appeal deadline stated on the notice has passed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

Is it possible to appeal a [notice of intent to assess from Massachusetts](https://massdocs-digital-mass-gov.s3.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/2018/nia-breakdown_0.pdf?XhtUKBJJBMlDelhABSXeP4QUH7TvZ1Sd) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181222234356/https://massdocs-digital-mass-gov.s3.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/2018/nia-breakdown_0.pdf?XhtUKBJJBMlDelhABSXeP4QUH7TvZ1Sd)) after the appeal deadline stated on the notice has passed? I saw the notice of intent to assess too late as I was traveling. (I can prove it with flight tickets if needs be)

---

Is it possible = Will the appeal be considered?

Comment: You can appeal anything but whether the appeal will be considered instead of just getting tossed out on the grounds that it is too late is another matter.

Comment: @DilipSarwate of course that's the underlying question... Will the appeal be considered?